# Batch creation of domain working in command line, but not through exec maven plugin

Tags: maven, glassfish, exec-maven-plugin, asadmin

I've written a small file containing a Glassfish domain creation sequence, that looks like this :

```
create-domain --adminPort 4848 --instancePort 8080 pouet
start-domain pouet
create-jdbc-connection-pool --datasourceclassname=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDataSource --restype=javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource --validationmethod=meta-data --description="Client datasource using an external Derby instance" --property port=1527:password=pouet:user=pouet:serverName=localhost:databaseName=pouet:connectionAttributes=create\\=true jdbc/datasource/pouet
create-jms-resource --restype javax.jms.ConnectionFactory --description "Standard pouet connection factory" jms/pouet/ConnectionFactory
create-jms-resource --restype javax.jms.Topic --property Name=jms_CrudServiceNotifier jms/CrudServiceNotifier
create-jms-resource --restype javax.jms.Topic jms/TaskExecution
create-jms-resource --restype javax.jms.Topic jms/TaskExecution/InDesign
deploy --force "C:\\Documents and Settings\\ndx\\.m2\\repository\\com\\netoprise\\neo4j-connector\\0.1-SNAPSHOT\\neo4j-connector-0.1-SNAPSHOT.rar"
create-connector-connection-pool --raname=neo4j-connector-0.1-SNAPSHOT --connectiondefinition=com.netoprise.neo4j.connection.Neo4JConnectionFactory  --property=xa=true:dir=\$\{com.sun.aas.instanceRoot\}/lib/databases/neo4j Neo4jPool
create-connector-resource --poolname=Neo4jPool neo4j/pool
```

I usually run all thoses steps through Glassfish [asadmin](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19798-01/821-1758/asadmin-1m/index.html) [multimode](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19798-01/821-1758/multimode-1/index.html).

When running all that by hand using the following instruction

```
E:\java-ext\glassfish3\bin\asadmin.bat --user "pouet" --passwordfile src\main\config\glassfish.password multimode --file target\config\current\create-domain.txt
```

It takes less than two minutes to execute.

But when running it through maven using the following pom configuration

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>create start and configure domain</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>exec</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>${glassfish.asadmin}</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>--user</argument>
                            <argument>"${glassfish.user}"</argument>
                            <argument>--passwordfile</argument>
                            <argument>"${glassfish.passwordFile}"</argument>
                            <argument>multimode</argument>
                            <!-- - - file is a multimode subcommand parameter, and not an asadmin parameter -->
                            <argument>--file</argument>
                            <argument>"${user.glassfish.config.path}/create-domain.txt"</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

It stays stalled at domain startup with the log last lines being

```
No domain initializers found, bypassing customization step
Domain pouet created.
Domain pouet admin port is 4848.
Domain pouet admin user is "pouet".
Command create-domain executed successfully.
Attempting to start pouet.... Please look at the server log for more details.....
```

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sysinternals/bb896653) indicates, for all process spawned by exec maven plugin, absolutely no CPU consumption.

Besides, exec maven plugin created command line is

```
[DEBUG] Executing command line: cmd /c E:\java-ext\glassfish3\bin\asadmin.bat --user "pouet" --passwordfile "E:\JavaWorkspace\pouet\pouet-ear/src/main/config/glassfish.password" multimode --file "E:\JavaWorkspace\pouet\pouet-ear/target/config/current/create-domain.txt"
```

which is totally identical to the one I entered by hand.

So ... what could possibly make that process hang ? And what could I do to fix that ?

**[EDIT]** Adding --verbose flag to start-domain instruction displays as last line before process hangs the following ones :

```
4 août 2011 16:05:58 com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncherLogger info
INFO: Successfully launched in 16 msec.
[#|2011-08-04T16:06:03.078+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|null|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1 (build 43)|#]

[#|2011-08-04T16:06:03.156+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|org.glassfish.ha.store.spi.BackingStoreFactoryRegistry|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry|#]

[#|2011-08-04T16:06:03.843+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=27;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Grizzly Framework 1.9.31 started in: 297ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:8181]|#]

[#|2011-08-04T16:06:03.859+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Grizzly Framework 1.9.31 started in: 266ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:4848]|#]

[#|2011-08-04T16:06:03.859+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=32;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Grizzly Framework 1.9.31 started in: 219ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:3700]|#]

[#|2011-08-04T16:06:03.859+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=29;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Grizzly Framework 1.9.31 started in: 391ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:8080]|#]

[#|2011-08-04T16:06:03.921+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=35;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Grizzly Framework 1.9.31 started in: 15ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:7676]|#]

[#|2011-08-04T16:06:04.109+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1 (43) startup time : Felix (3 360ms), startup services(1 656ms), total(5 016ms)|#]

[#|2011-08-04T16:06:05.281+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.server|_ThreadID=46;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|JMXStartupService: Started JMXConnector, JMXService URL = service:jmx:rmi://172.27.63.177:8686/jndi/rmi://172.27.63.177:8686/jmxrmi|#]
```

If someone knows what is to be started after JMX, and what could possibly prevent it from starting, it would, i think, help me fix that weird bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having done more maven katas than I ever expected to do, I've now found a solution. This goes (obviously) the [maven-antrun-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/run-mojo.html) way.

using so, i replaced the maven exec configuration with the following maven antrun code

```
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>create start and configure domain</id>
                            <phase>process-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                                <target>
                                    <exec executable="${glassfish.asadmin}" dir="${glassfish.asadmin.path}"
                                        failonerror="true" vmlauncher="false">
                                        <arg value="--echo"/>
                                        <arg value="true"/>
                                        <arg value="--interactive"/>
                                        <arg value="false"/>
                                        <arg value="--user"/>
                                        <arg value="${glassfish.user}"/>
                                        <arg value="--passwordfile"/>
                                        <arg value="${glassfish.passwordFile}"/>

                                        <arg value="multimode"/>

                                        <arg value="--printprompt=false"/>
                                        <arg value="--file"/>
                                        <arg value="${user.glassfish.config.path}/create-domain.txt"/>
                                    </exec>
                                </target>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
```

And it perfectly works !